# How can I extract a string within square brackets in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Given a string such as "Hello [world]", how would I get the value of the text inside the square brackets with xslt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substring-before(substring-after(root, '['),']')
```

Where "root" is the node having your string.

Comment: This only returns the first bracketed occurrence. For text `Stuff [foo] more stuff [bar]` you'll get back `foo` only.  If you need both it's a more complex problem.